# Flutter firestore check if document with specific id exists

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check if the firestore document with a specific id exists. Actually, my idea is to store and fetch user-specific data from firestore. If there is no user-specific data uploaded it will show "no data to show" in the app. Till now what I have done is adding data to firestore with document id equals to the current user's UID.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("doc_folder").doc(currentuser!.uid).set(data);
```

now I am unable to check if the firestore database contains any document with this data. By far, I have reached:

```
class Crud {
getData() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('doc_folder')
        .where("userId", isEqualTo: currentUser!.uid)
        .get();
  }
}
  @override
  void initState() {
    crud.getData().then((result) {
      snap = result;
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return Container(
snap != null? //if code
: //else code
)
}
```

The above code returns "document exists" even if the data does not exist with the current user's UID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line from your code returns a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) which is **not** nullable:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('doc_folder').where("userId", isEqualTo: currentUser!.uid).get()
```

and you assign the returned value of `QuerySnapshot` to `snap` and perform the following:

```dart
snap != null ? ... : ...
```

However, this condition will be true regardless of whether a document exists.

You should instead check [`docs`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html) property from `QuerySnapshot`, which is a list of the document snapshots returned for your query.

I'd prefer the widget of [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) over calling `getData()` in `initState` for this example to make it clear:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    future: crud.getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        if (snapshot.data.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          // Document exists
        } else {
          // Document does not exist
        }
      } else {
        // Show a loading widget
        // ...
      }
    },
  );
}
```

### Full Example

```dart
class Crud {
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('doc_folder')
        .where("userId", isEqualTo: currentUser!.uid)
        .get();
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  final crud = Crud();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: crud.getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final querySnaphost = snapshot.data; // Get query snapshot

          if (querySnaphost.docs.isNotEmpty) {
            // Document exists
            final documentSnapshot =
                querySnaphost.docs.first; // Get document snapshot
            return Text('${documentSnapshot.data()}'); // Get the data
          } else {
            // Document does not exist
            return Text('Document does not exist.');
          }
        } else {
          // Show a loading widget
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how to get the data from the snapshot and refresh the page using setState?

Comment: `snapshot.docs` is a list of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`s and `QueryDocumentSnapshot` has a method called `data()` which you can use to get the data of the document snapshot. For using `setState()`, take a look at the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Comment: I am new to flutter I would suggest showing the full code.... the above code throws 2 errors one at the builder: "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type". another one at the snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty: "The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>'."

Comment: Currently, I am checking by using `snap > 0? //if code` (The Code is working fine as expected) is it a good practice to do so?

Comment: should I build the app inside the if-else and inside the Future builder, I mean is it a good practice? example: `return Future ................//code sent by you  if (querySnaphost!.docs.isNotEmpty) { return Container(..........  // app layout if data is available for this user); }else{ return Container(........ //app layout if data is not available for this user);}`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by building app inside, but FutureBuilder is a widget just like the ones you create. You can for sure put your logic inside it, but try to split your app to widgets as far as possible. Don't build everything in a single FutureBuilder.

Comment: tried to code the Future builder inside the body but it seems like it reads twice from data on reload and while writing the data to the database it reads a total of 6 times and writes once. How to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that value of snapshot is not null even though document doesn't exists. So use below code:-

```
QuerySnapshot snap=await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('doc_folder').where("UserId", isEqualTo: currentuser!.uid).get();

if(snap.docs.isNotEmpty)
     DocumentSnapshot doc=snap.docs.first;
     print(doc['username']);//like this you can access data
else{
     print("Doc doesn't exits");
}
```

Comment: how can I retrieve the document data?

Comment: getting an error: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>'

Comment: Can you update your function in the ques?

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Got late, Stewie have posted the right one. Give it a try

Comment: Currently, I am checking by using `snap > 0? //if code` (The Code is working fine as expected) is it a good practice to do so?

Comment: It is better, if you use snap.docs.length>0

Comment: okay, but it is a good practice right? also the state does not refresh even when I call setState in the initState I had to hot reload the app to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

```
    var 
    doc=FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('doc_folder')
    .where("userId", isEqualTo: 
    currentUser!.uid)
    .get();
    if(doc.exist){
    print('exist');
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight problem with your code. `build()` is called while `async crud.getData()` is still running. Therefore snap will be have its default value. If snap's default value is not null, then `snap != null` will be true and you might assume your snap has its intended value.

Full working code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Crud crud = Crud();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: crud.getData(),
        // above is called everytime the widget is rebuilt which is not optimal
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Something went wrong');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return CircularProgressIndicator();

          if (snapshot.data.docs.isNotEmpty) {
            print('document exists');
            print(snapshot.data.docs.map((e) => e.data()));
            return Container();
          } else {
            print('document does not exist');
            return Container();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Crud {
  Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where("userId", isEqualTo: 'c1fG8zo0OWgHsPClEKWN')
        .get();
  }
}
```

Comment: "// above is called everytime the widget is rebuilt which is not optimal" Please explain how to optimize?

Comment: For some reason, `crud.getData()` future is called everytime the widget is rebuilt. This should not be so. A future should be called only once.

Comment: replace `crud.getData()` with `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where("userId", isEqualTo: 'c1fG8zo0OWgHsPClEKWN').get(),` and this would be called just once. So you can use this solution.

Comment: Did my solution work? if yes, kindly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Company')
        .doc('1235')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      if (value.exists) {
      // Do something Here
}
```

The question asked to check if the document exists, and the answer accepted only works if docId is stored as field in that doc. Needs Review.